# What does 'bite to it' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In House of Cards, Zoe says:

> There's no bite to it.
>
> She told me about a profile she's working on.

What does 'bite to it' mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Cambridge Dictionary...](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bite)

> **bite** noun
>   ...
>    (STRONG TASTE)
>    *If food has bite, it has a sharp or **strong taste** - e.g. I like mustard with bite*
>   ...
>    (STRONG EFFECT)
>    *a **powerful effect** - e.g. This satire has real bite*

Note that the second definition is effectively just a metaphorical extension of the first, which itself is extended from the "literal" sense of the verb ***bite = use one's teeth to cut into something***.

---

I don't know the full context of OP's cited usage, so I can't say for sure which of those two definitions applies. But Zoe is probably expressing disappointment that the profile lacks metaphorical [**"punch"**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/punch) - *the power to be interesting and have a strong effect on people*.

---

Note that the construction ***There's no X to it*** is simply an alternative way of expressing the assertion ***It has no X*** or ***It lacks X*** - usually restricted to contexts where one might reasonably *expect* X to be somehow associated with whatever "it" is.

Comment: The edit "unlocked" my downvote.  It is "locked" after 10 minutes and can only  be reversed if the post is edited.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. When I've realised my mistake *more than X minutes after mis-voting*, I've sometimes just edited an invisible space into the post, which "unlocks" it so I can reverse my error. Can't you edit *mine?*

Comment: Never occurred to me.